# Invalid scope requested: chat:write:bot

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

I am implementing slack bot where user will execute the slash command and bot will post the ephemeral message to the chhanel.

Bot should be able to respond even to the private channels if user sends the slash command in private channel.

I implemented it with classic slack oauth flow and I was able to implement it using "chat:write:bot" command and now I want to upgrade oauth flow to v2 in which I am unable to request "chat:write:bot" command.

How can I request "chat:write:bot" scope in oauth v2? Or is there any another work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try requesting `chat:write` instead of `chat:write:bot` scope: `chat:write` should work in Oauth v2 and it is used to send messages into channels.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I should also be able to send messages to user's private channel who installs the app. Using chat:write scope, I can send messages only to public channels.